# Dividing array so sum of subarray maximums is minimised

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I can only think of a brute force way to solve this. Interested to see what Algo SO community would come up with.

Giving an arr `a` and an integer `x` (1<x<=len(a)). Wihout reordering the array divide the array into x subarrays `s1, s2....sx` such that the sum of `max(s1) + max(s2)....+ max(sx)` is the minimum out of all possible combinations of sum of subarrays (see example below). return an array with x-1 indexes containing the index i (not inclusive) where the split happens `a[0:i], a[i+1:i2], a[i2+1: i3].....a[ix:]`.

Example:

```
a = [10,30,40,20,50]
x = 2
return = [1]
```

splitting the array at index 1 into [10] and [30,40,20,50]

would result `max([10]) + max([30,40,20,50]) = 60` which is the minimum out of all other ways to split array.

other possible splits -

- cannot split at index 0 because then it would only result in 1 array and x = 2
- split at index 2 = max([10,30]) + max([40,20,50]) = 80
- split at index 3 would result 90
- split at index 4 would result 90
- split at index 5 not allowed because then it would only result in 1 array and x = 2

Comment: I will update the question. minimum out of all possible sum of possible combinations of subarrays (other ways to split the array)

Comment: So you dont want a brute force?

Comment: @adirabargil Brute force takes exponential time.  Dynamic programming takes `O(len(a) * x)`.  Even with fast computers, you generally don't want brute force.

Comment: Won't you always partition the smallest item at the end of the list in order to group the larger items together? Given an `n` greater than one, you will partition the smallest item off the end, the recursively address the rest the same way?

Comment: @MarkMeyer, the arr should not be re-ordered. I will add that clarification

Answer (score 3):

This is a dynamic programming problem.

First build up the following data structure.

```
for each position in the array
    for each count of how many splits
        (current max, sum of maxes, position of last split)
```

For example in your problem the data structure would look like this:

```
[   # One group, no splits
    [(10, 10, 0)], # 2 groups, 1 split
    [(30, 30, 0), (30, 40, 1)],
    [(40, 40, 0), (40, 50, 1), (40, 80, 2)],
    [(40, 40, 0), (20, 50, 1), (20, 70, 3)],
    [(50, 50, 0), (50, 60, 1), (50, 100, 2)], # the choices are equal
]
```

This can be created with a straightforward double loop.  You start off with `[[(a[0], a[0], 0)]]`.  And to figure out the `i, j` entry you have to look at starting a new group after the `(i-1, j-1)` entry or adding the current element to the last group in the `(i-1, j)` entry.

Once you have this, start with the last position of the array and the desired number of splits.  The data structure tells you where the last split was, and you go to that position and down one split to find where the one before was.  Follow that cookie crumb trail back and you'll find all of the splits.

In your example, the `(len(a), x)` entry is at `(4, 1)` and has value `(50, 60, 1)`.  The previous entry is at `(1, 0)` and has value `(10, 10, 0)`.  We ignore the split at the boundary and get `[1]` as the answer.

If you wanted to make `x=3`, then you'd start at `(50, 100, 2)`, go back to `(40, 50, 1)`, then to `(10, 10, 0)` and get an answer of `[1, 2]`.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on your algo? What is the base case of Db and how does the metrix get filled? I am not following this part `(current max, sum of maxes, position of last split)`.

Comment: @OLIVER.KOO I added your sample problem as an example.

Comment: Note, my "the choices are equal" comment is because splitting the second time at 2 and 3 give the same total.

Comment: @גלעדברקן A subarray is contiguous, so there can't be multiple groups to try.  So there are only two possibilities - start a new group or extend the previous group.  If we extend the previous group all we need to know is whether A[i] is smaller than the existing max (in which case max and sum of maxes is the same) or larger (in which case max and sum of maxes increase in tandem).

Comment: @גלעדברקן Moving the group start to the right because of finding a new max can have two results.  Either it doesn't change the max of the previous group, in which case it doesn't matter, or it does change the max of the previous group, in which case the sum gets worse. Either way there is no reason to move it to the right.

Answer (score 0):

For Max(sx) to become as small as possible, we should always strive to create subarrays with as small numbers as possible. So simply divide the input list into single-element lists with the smallest possible value:

```
arr = [10,30,40,20,50]
n = 2
a = []

def subarray(a):
    r = []
    while (len(r) <= n-2):
        r.append(a[:1])
        a = a[1:]
    r.append(a)
    return r

def calculate(a):
    r = 0
    for i in subarray(a):
        r += i[-1]
    return r

print(calculate(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute force isn't that bad if you can structure it to use memoization.

The approach it to recursively make a left-right split to determine the best solution combining each left-side prefix with the best solution for one less split of the right-side.  Since this is going to compute the same right side splits multiple times, memoization (keeping past results in memory for reuse) will short circuit most of the exploration branches.

```
from functools import lru_cache
from itertools import accumulate
def minMaxSum(A,x):
    
    @lru_cache()                # memoization for
    def findBest(start,splits): # best split from start position to end of A

        R = A[start:] # right-side/remaining elements

        # base cases (no recursion)
        if splits == 1:      return max(R),[R]
        if splits == len(R): return sum(R),[[r] for r in R]
        
        # progressively increasing size of left side subarray
        bestSum   = sum(R)+1           
        maxLeft   = 0
        for i,r in enumerate(R[:len(R)-splits+1],1):
            if r >= bestSum: break   # won't improve on best at this point
            maxLeft = max(maxLeft,r) # max for left side          
            subSum,subArrays = findBest(start+i,splits-1) # recurse right side
            subSum += maxLeft
            if subSum>=bestSum: continue # track improvement to best solution
            bestSum   = subSum
            bestSplit = [R[:i],*subArrays] # left side + best right side solution
        return bestSum,bestSplit
    
    # convert to break indexes and return solution
    maxSum,subArrays = findBest(0,x)
    breaks = list(accumulate(map(len,subArrays)))[:-1]
    return breaks,maxSum,subArrays
```

output:

```
print(*minMaxSum([10,30,40,20,50],2))
# [1] 60 [[10], [30, 40, 20, 50]]
    
print(*minMaxSum([10,30,40,20,50],3))
# [1, 2] 90 [[10], [30], [40, 20, 50]] 

print(*minMaxSum([40,30,40,20,50],3))
# [3, 4] 110 [[40, 30, 40], [20], [50]]

print(*minMaxSum([40,25,30,45,40,20,35,50],5))
# [1, 2, 5, 6] 180 [[40], [25], [30, 45, 40], [20], [35, 50]]

A = [i%5+1 for i in range(37)]
x = 11
print(*minMaxSum(A,x))
# [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36] 27
# [[1], [2], [3, 4, 5], [1], [2], [3, 4, 5], [1], [2],
# [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1], [2]]
```